# Mostrar tempo de sessão restante

Tags: session, jsp, servlet, timeout

Estou trabalhando com JSP e Servlet. Quero mostrar na página jsp o tempo restante para expirar a sessão que defini no meu web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Alguém já fez algo do tipo?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o método `getLastAccessedTime()` que retorna o tempo (em milissegundos) da última requisição associada a sessão.

E então, usar o método `getMaxInactiveInterval()` para obter o intervalo tempo máximo (em segundos) que o *container* irá manter esta sessão aberta.

Tendo esses dois valores, basta subtrair o tempo de sessão pelo tempo da última requisição, lembrando que um método retorna o valor em milissegundos enquanto o outro devolve em segundos:

```java
Long segundos = session.getMaxInactiveInterval() -
                (System.currentTimeMillis() - session.getLastAccessedTime()) / 1000;
```

A conversão, para minutos por exemplo, pode ser feita por meio de um objeto [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html):

```java
long minutosRestantes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(segundos);
out.print(minutosRestantes); // Exibe o tempo (em minutos) restante
```

Answer (score 1):

Com a classe HttpSession (representada pelo objeto implícito `session` no JSP) você pode recuperar o tempo do ultimo acesso através do método `getLastAccessedTime()` que retornará o tempo em milisegundos, assim você poderá manipulá-lo usando alguma classe de datas com `Calendar` ou `Date`